# bitbake -c savedefconfig overwrites current configuration

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Yocto environment for an ARM embedded board.
Following [these](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=Yocto_Customizing_the_Linux_kernel) instructions I'm having hard time to change the kenerl configuration.
Basically I did:

1. `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`
2. enabled a new driver (i.e. `PPP`)
3. save
4. check new the items in `.config`
5. `bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel`
6. now both `defconfig` and `.config` don't have the `PPP` module anymore
7. even more: entering again the `menuconfig` it is disabled

Why it does not work as expected?

Comment: Normally bitbake should tell where it stored the generated defconfig. It will not be in the meta-layer. You still have to copy the file to your meta-layer next to the bb of the kernel.  Note there is also the 'diffconfig' which will save only the difference in a fragment file. And the last note, not all linux kernel recepies works with these fragments.

Comment: @vermaete, yes, it tells me the defconfig is in the same locations of .config, under the tmp/work directory. This is the problem! After saving it also the .config file loses the changes I've made.

Comment: Well, at the end the defconfig with the modifications should be copied to the meta-layer (eg meta-myproject/recepies-kernel/linux/linix-imx/defconfig). You can do this with tools (eg devtool ) or just with a cp. When the modifications are there, the next bitbake will start using them. Note, devtool makes these things easier during the itterations of development.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain it better: the defconfig **does not** contain my changes. I've already done the next steps, but of course cannot work because the defconfig (and .config) loses my changes jusy after savedefconfig.

Comment: So, if you save the config in the menuconfig, the changes are in the .config file? A diff between the defconfig in the meta layer and the .config can prove it. When you copy the .config to the defconfig and redo the menuconfig, are the canges still in? If so, it is indeed a behaviour of savedefconfig.

Comment: Exactly, after saving in menuconfig the changes are in .config file only. After `savedefconfig` the disappears in .config and are not transferred to defconfig.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good approach but the only way I'm going to use is to copy .config to defconfig in my meta-custom-layer....