# Yocto: overriding kernel configuration

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135867/bitbake-c-savedefconfig-overwrites-current-configuration) question.
In order to customize the kernel configuration I created in my custom layer this structure:

```
$ tree recipes-kernel/
recipes-kernel/
└── linux
    ├── files
    │   └── <image>-defconfig
    └── linux-stm32mp_4.19.bbappend
```

Where the `defconfig` file is actually the `.config` used to manually compile the kernel (see the other question). The `bbappend` file contains the following code:

```
SRC_URI += "file://<full-path>/meta-custom-layer/recipes-kernel/linux/files/<image>-defconfig"
KERNEL_DEFCONFIG_stm32mp1_<variant> = "{WORKDIR}/<image>-defconfig"
```

I'm sure the file is processed because if I change the name of the defconfig `bitbake` raises a file not found error.

The problem is the compiled kernel **does not have** my customization.
But if I copy my defconfig to the build directory (i.e. `tmp/work/stm32mp1_<variant>-openstlinux_eglfs-linux-gnueabi/linux-stm32mp/4.19-r0/linux-stm32mp1-<variant>-standard-build/.config`) and manually `bitbake virtual/kernel`) it does.

So it seems it searches and finds my defconfig but then it ignores it.
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your mistake. But I know what I do.

Instead of trying to overload defconfig I let bitbake generate kernel fragments (diffs from the kernel supplied defconfig): https://edison-fw.github.io/meta-intel-edison/5.1-Bitbake-tricks#configuring-the-kernel-and-grab-the-kernel-fragment

Then I add the fragments to my recipe: https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison/blob/warrior/meta-intel-edison-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_5.4.0.bb

Comment: I see they use `linux-yocto` instead of `virtual/kernel`. Are they different things?

Comment: I created the fragment file (and checked it contains my customization!). But they suggest to place the file inside the original layer? Should not be better to place it inside the custom one?

Comment: meta-intel-edison is already custom one. It has it's own recipe for linux-yocto as it is newer then any in yocto (so can not be appended). Of course you can create a new layer and have that append to the one in meta-intel-edison. Or you can patch meta-intel-edison. Whatever suits you best.

Comment: It *seems* this did the trick: insert `KERNEL_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS += "/<full-path>/meta-custom-layer/recipes-kernel/linux/files/fragment.cfg"` to the `.bbappend` above.